# Issue transaction without being online

Tags: transactions, blockchain, smartcontracts

Is there some way in which `User A` who could load a transaction onto the block chain and if some other `User B` who is willing to pay `User A`, without `User A` being online could release the loaded transaction. Something like  a `smart contract` ?

Lets say if `A` and `B` wants to exchange some bitcoin transactions between each other. But they 
both dont know each other before. `A` list his address some where and when `B` sees it, `B` will 
issue a bitcoin transaction to `A`.

`A` might not be online when `B` has issued this transaction. But `B` should receive back a
transaction from `A`, if `B` has payed to `A`'s address.  How's it possible ?

Comment: So, `B` wants to pay `A`. `B` is online, but `A` is not? Or did you mistype and `B` is the one that is offline?

Comment: `B` is online, but `A` is not, `A` has already loaded a transaction onto the `blockchain`. And if some one is willing to pay to `A`, the pre-loaded transaction should be released.

Comment: So, `B` would pay, and then the transaction of `A` would be released? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Murch please find the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

The blockchain does not contain yet-to-be-published transactions to publish them based on conditions.  The blockchain is the structure that transactions are published *to*.  There is no such thing as a "pre-loaded transaction" that can be "released".  Either `A` (Alice) or `B` (Bob) has to publish it.

What Alice *can* do is give Bob a pre-signed transaction that spends an output from a transaction from Bob that has not been published yet.  This way, when Bob publishes his transaction, he can now publish the pre-signed transaction from Alice, but can't publish it beforehand.  This requires more coordination that I believe you are looking for, but it's possible.  It would go like this:

1. Bob creates a transaction, B<sub>1</sub>, with an output to Alice, but does not sign nor publish it.
2. Bob sends Alice B<sub>1</sub>, still unsigned.
3. Alice uses the output on B<sub>1</sub> as an input on her own transaction, A<sub>1</sub>.  This transaction has an output that pays to Bob.
4. Alice signs A<sub>1</sub>, but can't publish it because it spends the still unpublished B<sub>1</sub>.  Instead, she sends the signed A<sub>1</sub> to Bob.
5. Alice can now go offline, as her part is complete.
6. Bob, now in possession of a signed A<sub>1</sub>, signs and publishes B<sub>1</sub> to the network.
7. With B<sub>1</sub> now published, A<sub>1</sub> is now a valid transaction, and Bob publishes it as well.

Again, I don't think this is exactly what you are looking for, but I don't think what you are looking for is possible.  Smart contracts generally require sending transactions back and forth before publishing to the blockchain.  You really can't have a smart contract with someone with whom you've never communicated.  The up-front communication is the contract part, and publishing to the blockchain is more like resolving the contract.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this was what you meant or not, but at Bitcoin 2014 I saw a prototype for NFC payments.

The `payer` was offline and using his smartphone to create a transaction, which he then directly sent to the `recipient` via Near Field Communication. Since it is a valid transaction, it doesn't matter who transmits it to the network, and therefore the `recipient` could just submit it instead of the `payer`.

That way, the `recipient` would get paid, even though the `sender` was and remained offline.