# Smart contracts in bitcoin

Tags: transactions, ethereum, smartcontracts

Is it possible in `bitcoin` to start a `smart contract` preloaded with some amount of money. And if some other user is ready to pay to the `smart contract` a certain amount of money, the `smart contract` should release the preloaded amount of money in the `smart contract` to the user who paid to it ?

Comment: This appears to be almost exactly the [same question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/45901/5406) you've already asked earlier. Is there a particular reason why you didn't update that question, and are asking again?

Comment: kind of the same, but I wanted to explore the possibility of having a `smart contract` within the current implementation of `bitcoin`

Comment: I think your confusion is with how smart contracts work in the Bitcoin network.  In Bitcoin, smart contracts require involvement from the participants of the contract, and is not simply executed on the blockchain autonomously.  Think of 2 lawyers drafting a legal contract.  They only need to go to court when there is a problem, otherwise all commuication is between them.  The blockchain is the court in this metaphor.  It doesn't perform the actions of the contract, it only enforces the rules.  The participants still need to be active.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53837/34190

Answer (score 1):

Had you seen http://rootstock.io/ ?
Keep in mind that the bitcoin script language is not [turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) as the [Ethereum VM](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=431513.0)

Comment: I saw that. But is it possible with the present implementation.

Comment: As you can read in the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) the scripting language was not inteded be for smart contracts.
Also, you can read [this](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/the-bitcoin-scripting-system-is-purposefully-not-turing-complete-why) and [this](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42331/is-ethereum-essentially-bitcoin-with-turing-complete-script) questions related the usage of smart contracts in XBT and ETH.
So, in the end, the answer will be NO